# Fail executing RSHELL to acess ESP32 using Micropython

Tags: esp32

An ESP32 was flashed with `micropython`, using `esptool` on Linux system ( Ubuntu 18.04 ). When I tried to run`rshell` after installing it, it seemed as it start executing, but did'nt reach to login part - `rshell --buffer-size=30 -p /dev/ttyUSB0`

BTW- connecting via `PUTTY` was successfull ( and so was flashing of micoropython )

what might be the reason for that ?